# Can't Log into Brand New Azure Virtual Machine created w/ Resource Manager

Tags: virtual-machines, azure, rdp, login

I just created a VM in Azure using the Resource Manager model. After it is setup, I downloaded an RDP client with this button:

[image]

But no matter what I try, I can't log in. The machine is running. The error I receive is:

```
Your credentials did not work
```

I have tried the following user names:

```
myCompanyDomain\user
user
.\user
\user
NameOfVM\user
```

I have checked, double checked, and tripple checked the password. I have read and followed all of the steps in this article: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/virtual-machines-troubleshoot-remote-desktop-connections/#wincred

Still can't connect. What am I missing?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because we're not Azure support.

Comment: I've seen plenty of other Azure questions on this forum.

Comment: They are largely about the VMs running on Azure, not the Azure control panel itself.

Comment: Did you read my question?  This is about a VM running on Azure... and how to RDP to it.

Comment: Sadly, I suspect you're going to have to get in touch with Azure support.  There's not a lot we can do about "my credentials don't work, even though I believe they're correct."  The only other thing I can think of is "boot your new VM off a Hiren's," which is something I've never done with Azure.

Comment: This seems to be some sort of bug in Azure related to my user.  When *I* create a VM, none of my co-workers or I can access it. When anyone else creates a VM (using the EXACT SAME steps) we can all access it.  I think this is going to end up being a support issue.  (deep breath)  Not what I needed right now.

Comment: @KatherineVillyard -- looks like you are right. See my comment below, under the answer by David

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, the root of this problem is still a mystery.  If we figure it out, I'll post the solution. For whatever weird reason, when I create a VM, nobody (none of my co-workers nor I) can access it.  When anyone else creates a VM using the SAME STEPS, we can all access it.  But, we found a work around.  [This article](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/virtual-machines-troubleshoot-remote-desktop-connections/) helped, but didn't get us all the way there.

Here's the work around script:

```
Login-AzureRmAccount

Get-AzureRmSubscription -SubscriptionName <Your Subscription Name>
```

Copy the Tenant Id returned above

```
Login-AzureRmAccount -TenantId <TenantId>

$vm = Get-AzureRmVM -ResourceGroupName <Your Resource Group Name> -Name <Your VM Name>

$cred = Get-Credential (this is the VM user credentials)

Set-AzureRmVMAccessExtension -ResourceGroupName <Your Resource Group Name> -VMName <Your VM Name> -Name VMAccessAgent -TypeHandlerVersion "2.0" -UserName $cred.UserName -Password $cred.GetNetworkCredential().Password -Location <Location of VM>

Update-AzureRmVM -ResourceGroupName <Your Resource Group Name>  -VM $vm
```

Answer (score 1):

To use RDP with the VM user, Use `local\username` or `.\username`. Both forms work; I just verified this with my own VM.

If that doesn't get you in, you have some other issue that's not network related (the error you're getting means you reached the VM).

Comment: This seems to be some sort of bug in Azure related to my user.  When I create a VM, none of my co-workers or I can access it. When anyone else creates a VM (using the EXACT SAME steps) we can all access it.  I think this is going to end up being a support issue.  (deep breath)  Not what I needed right now.